# What is the capacity of this circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

I simply can't figure out what the capacity of this circuit is.

I can do the math myself, I just need a hint how to create an equivalent circuit where it is obvious what is parallel and what is in series...

[image]

Comment: Teachers need to stop asking these nonsensical questions. A student won't learn a thing from analyzing this particular circuit with its symmetry. Either we teach them how to analyze a general circuit (which we should) or we stop asking trick questions like this that are of no value in real life, whatsoever.

Comment: It is not a homework ... I was just struggling with this kind of exercise, so I created random circuits to solve them

Comment: Then you made the same mistake as a teacher would have if he had given you this circuit: there is nothing to learn from this one. You need to study Kirchhoff's laws and learn how to convert them into systems of equations. Start by assigning variables ($u_1, u_2...$) to node voltages and currents ($i_{C1}, i_{C2}$ etc..) trough components, then use the equations you know that connect the current trough a component to the voltage across it.

Comment: Congratulations ! :-) - as CuriousOne says, you have created a classic special case. As he says, learn to apply Kirchiff's laws. BUT in this case - remove C5, work out the potential at the C!/C4 and C3/C6 boundaries and see how they compare. What happens, regardless of what you connect between these points?

Comment: since potential difference is zero, nothing?

Comment: @CuriousOne : I disagree. Students need practice to gain confidence and to master techniques. This circuit offers practice (1) in redrawing and simplifying, and (2) in recognising and making use of symmetry. The benefits are not confined to the analysis of electrical circuits, because the skill of recognising and applying simplifications, similarities and symmetries is useful throughout physics.